# JNA - Use structure array as byref argument

Tags: struct, arguments, pass-by-reference, jna

I know parts of this issue is covered by some posts here and I have looked at them and tested some but with no luck.
I have this native method signature which should populate the provided **CBadgeData structure array** with results:

```
int elc_GetBadges(int nHandle, char* cErr, int* nRecCount, CBadgeData** arr)
```

The CBadgeData structure is implemented as follows:

```
package test.elcprog;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import com.sun.jna.Pointer;
import com.sun.jna.Structure;

public class CBadgeData extends Structure{

    public static class ByReference extends CBadgeData implements Structure.ByReference { }

    public int nBadgeID, nTrigger, nExtraData;
    public String cName;

    public CBadgeData(Pointer pointer){
        super(pointer);
    }

    public CBadgeData(){ }

    public String ToString() {
        return nBadgeID + "," + nTrigger + "," + nExtraData + "," + cName;
    }

    @Override
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        String[] s = new String[]{"nBadgeID","nTrigger","nExtraData","cName"};
        return Arrays.asList(s);
    }
}
```

My last try to craft this argument and call the method looked like this:

```
CBadgeData.ByReference[] badges = new CBadgeData.ByReference[max_items];
new CBadgeData.ByReference().toArray(badges);
int ret = inst.elc_GetBadges(handle, err, recCount, badges);
```

It fails with segmentation error.

My Question is what Java type should be provided here as an argument for the native `CBadgeData**` in the call to `elc_GetBadges`?

**EDIT -1-**

Populating the array myself (with or without terminating null pointer) didn't work and caused further Seg crashes. I then used Pointer[] arg as technomage suggested:

```
Pointer[] pointers = new Pointer[max_items];
for(int i=0; i<max_items; i++){
    pointers[i] = new CBadgeData.ByReference().getPointer();
}
int ret = inst.elc_GetBadges(handle, err, recCount, pointers);
```

This caused no error but seems to not make any changes to the returning struct which should have contain 4 items in this case:

```
int bid = new CBadgeData(pointers[i]).nBadgeID; // this returns null for all items
```

Using explicit read() / write() on the struct led to Seg crashes again (on the read):
Any idea what am I still missing here?

**EDIT -2-**

Interestingly enough - using the `Memory.get` directly, after calling the native method, gets the correct results:

```
Memory m= (Memory)pointers[0];
System.out.println("1st int: "+m.getInt(0)); // this gets 24289 which is 5ee1
System.out.println("2nd int: "+m.getInt(4)); // this gets 3
System.out.println("3rd int: "+m.getInt(8)); // this gets 255
System.out.println("String: "+m.getString(12)); // this gets "Badge[5EE1]" as supposed
```

But the `read()` still crashes. Any thoughts?

Comment: Memory dump prints the bytes in addressable order.  On intel (little-endian), the least-significant bytes appear first, so [e15e0000] represents the value 00005ee1.  This is called byte ordering, and is most definitely *not* the same thing as alignment.

Comment: Please post the native and Java structure definitions.

Comment: I understand (removed from q).
So what might be the problem with the `read()` while reading the `Memory` directly works fine?

Comment: OK this is resolved by changing the structure `Public String cName` to `char[]` with a fix length.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Actually the `byte[]` worked better then the `char[]`.

Comment: Java `byte[]` is for native `char`.  Java `char` is for `wchar_t`.

Comment: In addition, you should use `Native.toString(byte[])` to convert the byte array to a `String`.  That function looks for a terminating NUL character, while new String(byte[]) creates a string whose length is the length of the byte array.

Answer (score 1):

I'm inferring that CBadgeData** input is intended to be an array of pointer to CBadgeData.

As such, the Structure.ByReference tagging is correct.

`Structure.toArray()` is probably *not* appropriate here, or at least not necessary (it allocates a contiguous block of structs in memory).  You can just populate your array with CBadgeData.ByReference instances.

Perhaps your callee is expecting a NULL pointer at the end of the array?  I don't see another indicator of the array length to the callee.

```
CBadgeData.ByReference[] badges = new CBadgeData.ByReference[max_items+1];
for (int i=0;i < badges.length-1;i++) {
    badges[i] = new CBadgeData.ByReference();
}
badges[badges.length-1] = null;
```

Pretty sure that works.  If for whatever reason there's a bug handling `Structure.ByReference[]`, I know that `Pointer[]` is reliable and will do the same thing.

**EDIT**

If you use `Pointer[]` instead of `Structure.ByReference[]` (please post a bug to the project site if `Structure.ByReference[]` does not work), you will have to manually call `Structure.write/read` before/after your native function call, since JNA will not know that the pointers reference structures that need to be synched with native memory.  I'd bet, however, that the cause of your crashes when using `Structure.ByReference[]` was simply that JNA was automatically calling `Structure.read()` after the call and triggered the same error that you see when calling it explicitly.

If you get a segfault on read, it likely means that your structure fields aren't properly aligned or defined, or (less likely) that you have corrupt data that can't be read properly.  To diagnose this, set `jna.dump_memory=true` and print out your struct after calling `Structure.write()` to see if the contents of the structure appear as you'd expect.  It'd also help to post the native and JNA forms of your structure here, if possible.

Comment: Thanks! Please see my 'answer' which follows your suggestions.
Why can't I 'answer' your response with full details but only with comments?

Comment: Generally, it makes most sense to put an addendum on your original question, clearly marked as such.

Comment: Did so - please see **EDIT -2-**